# RPG skeleton, Part 1 - The Character

Tags: c++, game, c++14, role-playing-game

I've been on a quest to learn C++, and to learn, I've started building a small Role-Playing-Game skeleton to help myself learn the language. I've tried to make sure that I've followed C++ styles/standards correctly.

This is the first "part" of my development of the skeleton, and it includes a usable class, `Character`. The `Character` class has the following attributes:

- `characterName` - The name of the character.
- `healthPoints` - How much health the player has. *(Stays within the range \$0\rightarrow\infty\$.)*
- `experiencePoints` - How much experience the player has. *(Stays within the range \$0\rightarrow\infty\$.)*

It also has the following methods:

- `applyRandomDamage` - Apply a random amount of damage to the player in a certain range.
- `applyDamage` - Apply a set amount of damage to the player.
- `addRandomExperience` - Add a random amount of experience to the player.
- `addExperience` - Add a set amount of experience to the player.
- `toString` - Display the player's statistics. (Name/Health/experience)

I'm wondering the following things:

- Is there an override so that I can just `std::cout` an instantiated `Character` object without having to create my own custom `toString` method?
- Is this designed appropriately? Is there anything that could be designed differently?
- Am I following the correct C++ styles/standards?
- Is this idiomatic C++?

**character.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

/// <summary>
/// Represents a character, with certain attributes, like
/// health points, or the character's name.
/// </summary>
class Character
{
public:
    std::string characterName;
    int         healthPoints;
    int         experiencePoints;

    Character(std::string c_characterName, int c_healthPoints, int c_experiencePoints);

    void applyRandomDamage(int minimumDamage, int maximumDamage);
    void applyDamage(int damage);
    void addRandomExperience(int minimumExperience, int maximumExperience);
    void addExperience(int experience);
    void toString();
};
```

**character.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include "character.h"

/// <summary>
/// The constructor for our character.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="characterName">The name of our character.</param>
Character::Character(std::string c_characterName, int c_healthPoints, int c_experiencePoints)
{
    characterName    = c_characterName;
    healthPoints     = c_healthPoints;
    experiencePoints = c_experiencePoints;
}

/// <summary>
/// Apply a random amount of damage to the player, based on
/// a low and a high value.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="minimumDamage">The minimum damage to apply.</param>
/// <param name="maximumDamage">The maximum damage to apply.</param>
void Character::applyRandomDamage(int minimumDamage, int maximumDamage)
{
    std::random_device                 randomDevice;
    std::mt19937                       engine(randomDevice());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(minimumDamage, maximumDamage);

    int damage = distribution(engine);
    healthPoints = healthPoints - damage >= 0 ? healthPoints - damage : 0;
}

/// <summary>
/// Apply a set damage to the character, rather than a
/// random amount in a certain range.
/// </summary>
void Character::applyDamage(int damage)
{
    healthPoints = healthPoints - damage >= 0 ? healthPoints - damage : 0;
}

/// <summary>
/// Add a random amount of experience to the player.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="minimumExperience">The minimum experience to add.</param>
/// <param name="maximumExperience">The maximum experience to add.</param>
void Character::addRandomExperience(int minimumExperience, int maximumExperience)
{
    std::random_device                 randomDevice;
    std::mt19937                       engine(randomDevice());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(minimumExperience, maximumExperience);

    int experience = distribution(engine);
    experiencePoints = experiencePoints + experience >= 0 ? experience + experience : 0;
}

/// <summary>
/// Add a set amount of experience to the player.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="experience">The experience to add to the player.</param>
void Character::addExperience(int experience)
{
    experiencePoints = experiencePoints + experience >= 0 ? experience + experience : 0;
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns a string value representing the character, e.g
/// health points, or the character's name.
/// </summary>
void Character::toString()
{
    std::cout << "Name: "       << characterName    << "\n";
    std::cout << "Health: "     << healthPoints     << "\n";
    std::cout << "Experience: " << experiencePoints << "\n";
}
```

**main.cpp (tests)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "character.h"

int main()
{
    Character character = Character("Billy Bob Jenkins", 100, 50);
    character.toString();

    character.applyRandomDamage(5, 10);
    character.addRandomExperience(5, 10);
    character.toString();

    character.applyDamage(50);
    character.addExperience(50);
    character.toString();

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Something I did not adderss in my answer: `Character character = Character("Billy Bob Jenkins", 100, 50);` can be rewritten as `Character character{"Billy Bob Jenkins", 100, 50};`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Don't recreate your random engine everytime**

Here:

```
std::random_device                 randomDevice;
std::mt19937                       engine(randomDevice());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(minimumExperience, maximumExperience);
```

This does not make it more random and can affect the quality of numbers you get. Random engines have some state. Generally you only want one engine, though you can have more, but you don't want it to be recreated everytime the function is called. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11984017) does a good job of explaining it:

> "... Think of a random number generator where the seed must be
>   maintained on a per-thread basis. Using a thread-local seed means that
>   each thread gets its own random number sequence, independent of other
>   threads.
>
> If your seed was a local variable within the random function, it would
>   be initialised every time you called it, giving you the same number
>   each time. If it was a global, threads would interfere with each
>   other's sequences. ..."
>
> — paxdiablo

So you can do something like this:

```
// credit: http://cpp.indi.frih.net/blog/2014/12/the-bell-has-tolled-for-rand/
auto& prng_engine()
{
  thread_local static std::random_device rd{};
  thread_local static std::mt19937 engine{rd()};

  // Or you can replace the two previous lines with:
  //thread_local static std::mt19937
  //  prng{std::random_device{}()};

  return engine;
}
```

**Don't try to be clever**

I find this line particularly unreadable:

```
experiencePoints = experiencePoints + experience >= 0 ? experience + experience : 0;
```

It can be replaced with:

```
if (experience >= 0)
    experiencePoints += experience * 2;
```

With a comment explaining *why* you're doing this (for example, I don't understand why you're doing `experience + experience`.) Documentation-generating comments are OK, but don't really do a good job of explaining the why rather than the what.

**Code duplication**

I find it ironic that you have a `addExperience` function right below where you've used its body in the function above. Try this:

```
void Character::addRandomExperience(int minimumExperience, int maximumExperience)
{
    // ...
    int experience = distribution(engine);
    addExperience(experience); // <---
}
```

**Your `toString` is not idiomatic**

Your comment says: "Returns a string value representing the character, e.g
health points, or the character's name." but your method actually has a return value of `void`. This is bad for your user.

Here's the thing. If you want your `toString()` to behave like users expect, make it a serialization method and decouple printing it with `std::cout`. What if you want it to output to a file instead? What if you just need to mess with the object in a serialized form without outputting it at all? Here's something simple but will need to be changed depending on your use case:

```
// Serializes for OUTPUT purposes. Don't use this for internal
// data handling
std::string Character::toString() const
{
    // to_string is C++11. Use stringstream in C++03
    return "Name: "      + characterName +
           "Health:"     + std::to_string(healthPoints) +
           "Experience:" + std::to_string(experiencePoints);
}

// return hash of properties, maybe for
// save file purposes
std::string Character::serialize() const
{
    // ...
}
```

Note: I've added `const` because you're not modifying anything (this is a "get" method.)

**Overloading `operator<<`**

Read the [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) FAQ on stackoverflow. In particular, this is what your stub should look like:

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421719#4421719

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Character& obj)
{
    os << obj.toString();
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this great review! I do have one question though, how should I go about properly generating random numbers with your function? Could you provide an example usage in your post?

Comment: @EthanBierlein Something like `return distribution(prng_engine());`

Comment: This is an exemplary code review.

Comment: I agree that the "particularly unreadable" line you've quoted is indeed as unreadable as you describe, but I think you've actually misparsed it: `+` binds tighter than `>=` and `? :`, so as written,  it's actually equivalent to `if (experiencePoints + experience >= 0) { experiencePoints = 2 * experience; } else { experiencePoints = 0; }` But I think the original code has a bug here, the second `experience` is meant to be `experiencePoints`, and what the OP *meant* to achieve is simply `experiencePoints += experience; if (experiencePoints < 0) experiencePoints = 0;`.

Comment: If I could upvote "Don't try to be clever" more than once, I would. Welcome to CR. Thank you for the great review.

Comment: @EthanBierlein along with this, if you didn't notice - you also have a duplicated call for damage. You can make `applyRandomDamage` call `randomDamage` for better code reuse.

Comment: Also, I'm not a huge fan of using `auto`, would `std::random_device&` work as a return type for `prng_engine`?

Comment: @EthanBierlein auto is great 'cause it forces the programmer to initialize the variable.

Comment: @CyberSpock And `auto` is not great. It takes away useful clarity from code.

Comment: @EthanBierlein any modern IDE has some kind of Intellisense, so no loss of clarity. auto enhances readability e.g. auto vs std::iterator_traits<// bla bla and in some cases it is even difficult to get the correct declaration right (e.g. types only known to the compiler)

Answer (score 8):

I would just like to add some ideas about your "healthPoints" and "experiencePoints". I find dangerous (in a maintenance way) to :

1. do the same check in every function applying damages/experience/whatever: as the logic is the same it should be all defined in one place!
2. let any function in this class to change these parameters (nothing prevents any function to modify *directly* your "healthPoints", as it's not even private, but even if it was so every function in your class could change it).
3. with this design you can by mistake add or subtract experience to health and vice versa, this should be disallowed by the compiler.

So what I would do would be to create a simple template containing the value and addition and subtraction methods which check that the behaviour is good. As a consequence, "AddDamage" and co won't need to check boundaries any more! The class should stay a POD and inline everything so the performance won't be hurt...

```
enum SpecType {HEALTH, MANA, EXPERIENCE};

template <SpecType T> class Spec
{
private:
    /* Could be unsigned int as only subtraction can
       be a problem (and we define it in the class),
       but beware exposing this to the outside xP */ 
    int points;
public:
    Spec<T>(int value) : points(value) {}
    // ...

    int Points() const
    {
      return points;
    }

    Spec<T> operator-=(int value)
    {
      if (value >= points)
        points = 0; // maybe do something about death too...
      else
        points -= value;

       return *this;
    }
};

// ...

class Character
{
public:
    std::string characterName;
    Spec<HEALTH>      healthPoints;
    Spec<EXPERIENCE>  experiencePoints;
    Spec<MANA>        manaPoints;
    // ...
}

// ...

Character::Character(std::string c_characterName, int c_healthPoints, int c_experiencePoints) : characterName(c_characterName), heathPoints(c_healthPoints), experiencePoints(c_experiencePoints) // just as easy
{}

void Character::applyRandomDamage(int minimumDamage, int maximumDamage)
{
    // ...

    int damage = distribution(engine);
    healthPoints -= damage; // <= so much easier, and no risk to forget checking for below zero or ...
}
```

If you want to add levels you could add them in the Spec class so your damage functions wouldn't have to care about it themselves too. Or derive healthPoint and add more operators which would take typed damage points (normal, blunt, aggravated, ...) so the calculus will differ depending on these...?

Little bonus: maybe create user literal for these types, cf. http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#UD-literals

Comment: Boost.Units safety fashion. Nice :)

Comment: For the first point there's also the ever popular `max(health - damage, 0)` which could also be a bit more efficient depending on the compiler.

Comment: Could you provide an example usage of the `Spec` class? I've worked a little bit with templates, but I'm not sure how to use the class here.

Comment: @Voo: only if he decides to keep "int"s, because with "unsigned int"s (health - damage) will always be >= 0 so max won't do the trick...

Comment: @Shautieh Oh I missed that you changed it from int to unsigned int. That's a pretty dangerous practice which is pretty much discouraged by any style guide I ever worked with. See for example [google's style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#Integer_Types)

Comment: @Voo: it's only discouraged if the value can be accessed and changed directly because people will all too often change it without thinking about the value "rolling" to max int, but here we made sure nobody (beside Spec class' own methods) could change it inadvertently, so I think it's perfectly fine in this case. It could be changed to an int and an assertion about it being greater than 0, but I think it conveys  the idea better while remaining foolproof this way.

Comment: @Shautieh If you read the actual linked style guide it says "Don't use an unsigned type" and furthermore "the advantages of such documentation are outweighed by the real bugs it can introduce [..] document that a variable is non-negative using assertions". The guidance is very clear: Unsigned introduces bugs and makes the code complicated for very little benefit. C's type promotion scheme is just too complicated, proof for that are the thousands of serious - including security relevant - bugs that have been caused by using unsigned over the years.

Comment: @EthanBierlein: you can use healthPoints just the same as if it was an int as long as you define the proper methods (that's my "// ..." line ^^'). It doesn't matter whether this is a template or not here: you should define the constructor from int, copy constructor, operator+, operator-, and any other kind of operators that you will need to mimic the int operations. I'll add a little example soon!

Comment: @Voo: I did have a look, but this style guide only complains about using unsigned ints *directly* : the example they give to explain how subtle bugs could be introduced  just *cannot* happen with this design as everything is closely encapsulated. The for loop would never go around to max int because it's strictly forbidden by the class methods. I do agree that using unsigned int out of the blue is generally a bad idea, but in a small utility class the risk is nil. I'll edit my answer to warn about the usage of unsigned int and tell people to consider using int if it can reassure them though ^^

Comment: @Shautieh What you're arguing is "as long as nobody does anything wrong this will work fine", which well, is *always* true. You just decided that the scope is small enough for this to be ok (so at how many lines is it not true any more?). But the real problem is that unsigned leaks across your interfaces because it clearly is *not* just an internal detail. Your example already demonstrates that: `public unsigned int Points() const` - now every caller has to deal with unsigned too. And sooner or later (sooner really) someone will pass this to an utility function that takes an int.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot I wrote this getter :0 Without this, the scope I was thinking about was really only one function (subtraction), and at most the other functions in the class as well. I'll change to int for the sake of simplicity and to prevent having to change the interface if Spec has to share its value as an integer with the outside world. Thanks.

Comment: @EthanBierlein: I added some examples (I hope I didn't do any mistake ^^) taken from your code. The test with zero will be done by the -= function defined in the template (just the same as if it was a normal class) so the "user code" don't need to even care when afflicting damages to any specs. The template can be specialised if you want to do something special just in the health point case and not in the experience one for example. Or you could give it a functor telling the class what to do when reaching zero (health => die, experience or mana => nothing?, ...).

Answer (score 8):

Many things have already been said about your code (I like how it looks from afar by the way :p). *But* I still want to add my two cents:

- [`#pragma once`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once) is not standard and it's highly unlikely that it will ever be standardized since the standard committee is working on a modules system. On the other hand, it should work on most compilers and will sometimes improve your compile times. If you don't want your [lint tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_%28software%29) to complain about it, you should replace it or complete it with [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard):

  ```
  #ifndef RPGGAME_CHARACTER_H_
  #define RPGGAME_CHARACTER_H_

  // Your code here...

  #endif // RPGGAME_CHARACTER_H_
  ```
- Try to include only the headers you need. If you decide to overload `operator<<` as suggested, character.h will only need to *know that `std::ostream` exists* and so you can include `<iosfwd>` in it. It's a header that contains the declaration of the classes from the IO streams library. On the other hand, character.cpp will probably need to know *what `std::ostream` is* and so you will need to include `<ostream>`. As long as you don't use `std::cout` and its friends, you don't need to include `<iostream>`.
- When you don't modify a value in a function, you can pass it by `const` reference instead of passing it by copy so that no unnecessary copies are performed:

  ```
  Character(const std::string& c_characterName, int c_healthPoints, int c_experiencePoints);
            ^^^^^            ^
  ```

  The rules are actually more complex than that. For example, small types (built-in ones such as numbers or pointers) tend to be passed by copy. Also, there are more subtles rules involving [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) and [move operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) but most of the time you're food using `const` references when you don't modify a parameter.
- Use the [constructor initialization list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) whenever you can. The difference between using it and simply initializing the member variables in the body of the constructor is that, using the initialization list, the object is *constructed with the right values*. On the other hand, when you initiallize the member variables in the body of the constructor, the object is constructed, *then* the member variables are assigned values, which means more potential work.

  ```
  Character::Character(const std::string& characterName, int healthPoints, int experiencePoints):
      characterName(characterName),
      healthPoints(healthPoints),
      experiencePoints(experiencePoints)
  {}
  ```

  Note that I deliberately changed the name of the variables you passed: the names before the parenthesis will correspond to the names of the member variables while those in the parenthesis will pick the parameter names before the member variables names. It's up to you how your name your variables though :p
- I see that you are using the MSVC documentation comments. If you want more portable comments, you could use [Doxygen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen) comments instead. They are generally used by more projects and understodd by more people.

Answer (score 3):

This was a small thing that I noticed. Rather than having two separate experience modification functions, and two different health modification functions, I could simply provide two possible function overloads. This means that the public portion of the `Character` class would have these signatures instead:

```
void applyDamage(int damage);
void applyDamage(int minimumDamage, int maximumDamage);

void applyExperience(int experience);
void applyExperience(int minimumExperience, int maximumExperience);
```

There then would be the subsequent implementations of these overloads in `character.cpp`. I figured that this implementation might be more user friendly, requiring the user to know less names.

Some of my variable names are, iffy. Here are a few I found, and their subsequent replacements:

- `characterName` -> `name`
- `healthPoints` -> `health`
- `experiencePoints` -> `experience`

I also decided that defining a base `Entity` class with methods like the character would be useful if I ever need to create entity-like creatures/NPCs.

```
class Entity
{
public:
    std::string name;
    int health;

    Entity(const std::string& name, int health);
    ...
}
```